# Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I want to use PyGtk to write GUI-based application. I have installed all the required dependencies mentioned on the site [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html). I didn't use the all-in-one installer but instead installed all the things I need manually. 
When i run the interactive mode to test the installation result, I typed in

```
import pygtk
import gtk
```

The `import gtk` gives me the error mentioned above. More specifically, it says

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from gtk import _gtk
```

However, it seems that there is only problems when importing gtk but this is exactly what I need.Things work fine if i do `import pango` something like that.

I am so frustrated but can not find a solution. 
I have already installed Gtk+ from the Gtk website and add the bin file to the system PATH.

BTW, I use windows 7 and it's 32 bit python that i installed.
Anyone can help? Thank you

Comment: try installing from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygtk

Comment: Hi, there. So try to install pygtk once again ? :)

Comment: yep, that site has a lot of binary packages for windows, it is often easier to install from there

Comment: I found the problem. It's because I installed GTK 3+ version but apparently that is a little bit way ahead of PyGTK. I just downloaded GTK 2+ and it is working perfectly when i test with import gtk and this time a window shows up. :) Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, those libs might come in handy again